# Linq: Split list by condition and max size of n

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, chunks

I want to transform an array:

```
["a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

to

`["a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b"]` or `["b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a"]`

I want to group the array in a way where a special condition matches. In my case when `item == 'a'` or `item == 'b'`. And these groups I want to chunck into groups of 2. I'm currently a bit confused how to do it the elegant way.

Can anyone help?

Maybe the following makes it more clear:

I like to group the array into 'a' and 'b'-items first like so:

a-group:

```
["a","a","a"]
```

and

b-group:

```
["b","b","b","b"]
```

then I want to chunk this into groups of 2:

a-group:

```
["a","a"]
["a"]
```

b-group:

```
["b","b"]
["b","b"]
```

And now I want to merge them together to get the result:

```
["a","a","b","b","a","b","b"]
```

(always 2 of each group merged together)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: did you made a mistake in the first array ? don't you mean `["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]` instead

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear what I am asking.
First I want to group the array into two groups to get only the 'a'-items and the 'b' items. Then I want to chunk this two groups into of max size of 2. Then I want to merge every group of 'a'-items with the groups of 'b'-items.

Comment: @BlackMatrix So you want a group then a bin(2).

Comment: Is it clearer now? Added some additional information.

Comment: @BlackMatrix much clearer. But what if the input is `["a","b","a","a","a","a"]` in there you find a group `b` with length of 1 with multiple sequence left to the first group `a`. What is the expected result of that ?

Comment: I added some more letters in the example above. The expected result would be to make it alternating "as much as possible" so the expected result in your example would be ["a","a","b","a","a","a"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to `GroupBy` your data. Let assume the object are `string` but it's irrelevant anyway it's your grouping condition that will change if you have anything other than that.

For this to work you will need MoreLinq or simply include the Batch extension which does the "group by 2 and 1 for left overs". Details can be found [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#batch)

> note that the `Batch(2)` can be changed to whatever you need. If you put `Batch(5)` and
>   you have 7 elements it will make 2 groups, one with 5 elements and one of 2 elements

```
 // be my data, 4 x a, 3 x b, 1 x c, 2 x d, As a list for easier linQ
 var data = new[] { "a", "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "b", "d", "d", "a" }.ToList();

 // group by our condition. Here it's the value so very simple
 var groupedData = data.GroupBy(o => o).ToList();

 // transform all groups into a custom List of List of List so they are grouped by 2 internally
 // each list level represent Grouping -> Groups of 2 (or 1) -> element
 var groupedDataBy2 = groupedData.Select(grp => grp.ToList().AsEnumerable().Batch(2).ToList()).ToList();

 // find the group with the maximum amount of groups or 2 (and 1)
 var maxCount = groupedDataBy2.Max(grp => grp.Count());

 // will contain our final objects listed
 var finalObjects = new List<string>();

 // loop on the count we figured out and try add each group one by one
 for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
 {
     // try each group
     foreach (var group in groupedDataBy2)
     {
         // add the correct index to our final list only if the current group has enough to fill
         if (i < group.Count)
         {
             // add the data to our final list
             finalObjects.AddRange(group[i]);
         }
     }
 }

 // result here is : a,a,c,b,b,d,d,a,a,b
 var results = string.Join(",", finalObjects);
```

Comment: I think you will be my hero :)
I want to try your code but it seems like the Partition method takes a lambda and not only an int. Do I miss any extension?

Comment: @BlackMatrix. Well the source code call other methods. The easiest is for sure to add the library to your project. There are 10 overloads. You probably took only one of them.

Comment: I installed the nuget package morelinq.3.1.0

Comment: @BlackMatrix i am checking and they removed that overload at some point. I am looking for the new one

Comment: Is it maybe an additional Extension? I tried to use several versions but couldn't find it yet.

Comment: @BlackMatrix just updated. `Partition` is `Batch` It's because my code already has a `Batch` extension and it was causing conflict so i changed it's name.

Comment: @Frank that's so awesome. Thank you very much :-) I'm so lucky

Answer (score 0):

I think for simplicity's sake converting your arrays into lists and then using `findall()` would be the easiest way to do this.

`List<char> list = new List<char>(['a', 'a', 'b'...]);`

if you use predicates, then you can automatically filter a list to pull out each of the two elements like below

`a_elements = list.findall((char c) -> { return c == item; });`

Then for b you can do

`b_elements = list.findall((char c) -> { return c != item; });`

where `(char c) -> { return c... }` is a predicate, a method returns true when an item in the list qualifies for the condition and false otherwise, you can also use Microsoft's Predicate class to form these, but I prefer lambda functions.

Now `a_elements` and `b_elements` are arrays containing matches for each corresponding `findall()` call

From there all you have to do is group the arrays in groups of two